# Can you make polarizing filters out of non-conductive materials?

Tags: visible-light, polarization

I have seen it said that Faraday cages and wire grid polarizers work because they are conductive, and light oriented along the slits will activate the motion of electrons that will then block the light from passing through. And I have seen it said that screens that are made out of non-conductive material, will be transparent to light.

And also the same for microwaves, that if you made screens of the same width for microwaves out of non-conductive material, they would be transparent to microwaves rather than shielding them. I've seen glass used an an example, that if you made a polarizing filter or Faraday cage or microwave screen out of glass with the same nanometer physical dimensions, it would be transparent to light.

I'm wondering, are the polarizing camera filters in this video at 0:23 made out of conductive material?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcqZHYo7ONs

They are able to polarize and block out light. Does this imply that they must be made out of a conductive material? Or is what I have read incorrect, and you actually can make polarizing filters out of non-conductive material?

Comment: Polaroid film (as in the polarizer, not something in a camera) is a plastic.

Comment: There is no requirement that polarizers be made of conductive substances. Calcite polarizers are a simple example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brewster%27s_angle, don't even need anisotropy